# how to select the nth li element that does not have display 'none' and does not have a specific class name

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I chose the last 'li' element that does not have display 'none' and is not one with 'more' className.
Is there a way other than looping through li element?

```
<div class="Header">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">aaa</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bbb</a></li>
      <li style="display: none;"><a href="#">ccc</a></li>
      <li class="more" style="display: inline-block;"><a>More…</a>
        <div class="more-content"><a href="#">aaa</a><a href="#">bbb</a><a href="#">ccc</a></div>
      </li>
<ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: How would you like to have it done? I don't think, I may be mistaken though, there is a way to do that just with CSS. Even if you can it will be hard to manage later on.

Comment: Use css3 features.  Otherwise why not loop though using jQuery?

Comment: So in your example @keerti, which one should be selected? `bbb`?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, use [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), and [`:last`](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/):

```
$('li:not(".more"):visible:last')
```

```js
$('li:not(".more"):visible:last').css('background','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Header">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">aaa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">bbb</a></li>
    <li style="display: none;"><a href="#">ccc</a></li>
    <li class="more" style="display: inline-block;"><a>More…</a>
      <div class="more-content"><a href="#">aaa</a><a href="#">bbb</a><a href="#">ccc</a></div>
    </li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. exactly what I wanted. Thanks